How to download gz file with urlconnection using Java
I am downloading the gz file using urlconnection and saving it as a BLOB in the DB.
However, when reading and decompressing the saved content, the following error occurs.
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid bit length repeat
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code -- missing end-of-block
Is the URL connection code for downloading the gz file wrong?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!


private boolean downloadTimeFile
    {
        String urlPath = "http://123.456.44:8080/AAAAA";
        int TIMEOUT_VALUE = 10000;
        byte file[] = getdownload2File(urlPath, TIMEOUT_VALUE);

        if (file == null || file.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private byte[] getdownload2File(String urlpath, int connectionTime) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            InputStream inputStream = getUrlInputStream(downloadUrl, connectionTime);

            if (inputStream == null) {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int last = 0;

            while (true) {
                last = inputStream.read(buffer);
                if (last == -1)
                    break;
                for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, last);
                }
            }

            baos.flush();

            return baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new byte[0];
        }

    }



